# Understanding vocab.txt of vinai/bertweet-base

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

While looking at vocab.txt [here](https://huggingface.co/vinai/bertweet-base/raw/main/vocab.txt), I was left wondering why the vocabulary for Bertweet is not continuous.
For instance, see the below sample:

```
...
dice 63328
)@@ 63327
struggled 63326
wraps 63324
Investors 63312
#summer@@ 63305
...
```

As you can see, after 63305, we have 63312, followed by 63324... what about the numbers in between?

2. Also, it feels a bit strange why vocabulary starts at around 3800.

```
르@@ 3800
utory 3798
...
```

Any explanations will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Each number denotes the frequency count that the corresponding word appears in the pre-training corpus.
- Only top 64k words are included in the vocab.